# How to have an independent application child class for android library projects

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library

I ran into a weird situation where I have to have 2 application sub classes for the application name property under  in manifest files..

I've developed a library which has its own initialization that I've to make in the application derived class. When I try to include this library in my parent application as a module the manifest merger throws an error saying multiple application names declared. But I've no control over the application project, What am I suppose to do If I want to have 2 different application sub classes for my library and the external application project?

Any notion would be appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you have any application subclasses? The [`Application` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) recommend against it in almost all cases. Without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to recommend anything other than to get rid of the `Application` subclasses entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I gotta have application class for my library project. Because, I've initialization like ACRA.init() and image loader has to made with in the application class so that I could use it every where inside my library. Well, In that I gotta have one application class, right?

Comment: Not really. Your library project can have a utility class that has a static `init()` method that accepts a `Context`, to which you can pass any `Context` and internally uses `getApplicationContext()` to do the initialization. Then you simply need to arrange for that utility method to be called from your actual application. It could include an internal flag to prevent multiple initialization calls from executing more than one initialization. You don't need to subclass `Application`.

Comment: Thanks again but, as you said "Then you simply need to arrange for that utility method to be called from your actual application." won't be an elegant solution here. 'Cause I've got no control over the actual application. What I'm doing is just to develop a library. And launch it onto the market place. Actual application will be developed by another organization. So, No control on the actual application.

Comment: You do have control over the actual application: it's the API for your library. Just like ACRA specifies that you _must_ call it's `init(Context)` method, you can make a similar specification. Any application built using your library will simply have to conform to your specification if it is to work properly.

Comment: Well, Perfect,  That's what I was looking for.. you saved my day my friend..